# Inserting into red black tree when the parent P is red but the uncle U is black

Tags: data-structures, red-black-tree

This is case 4 in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) when inserts a node in red-black tree.

As the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Y1Qf.png) show, the node "U" does not seem to be a NIL, because it has chlidren.

But is it a red-black tree?

Is the picture wrong or i miss something?

Answer (score 0):

> But is it a red-black tree?

No. This is a red-black tree after a Node has been inserted, in this case N. This is all part of the procedures to fixup the tree so it is again, a red-black tree.

The picture is not wrong.

When insertion occurs, the new node will be at the bottom, a leaf node and it is normally Red. The fixup procedure works towards the root (and is guaranteed to work).

In so pseudo-algorithmic terms, the algorithm is

```
LOOP
   P = PARENT(N)
   IF P == NULL THEN
      'N MUST BE ROOT
      N.COLOUR = BLACK
      RETURN
   ENDIF
   IF P.COLOUR == BLACK THEN
      'FIXUPS HAVE ENDED
      RETURN
   ENDIF
   'NOTE: SINCE PARENT IS RED AND PREVIOUSLY WAS A RED-BLACK TREE THEN
   'GRANDPARENT EXISTS AND MUST BE BLACK AS ROOT NODE IS BLACK
   G = GRANDPARENT(N)
   U = UNCLE(N)
   IF U.COLOUR = RED THEN
       'COLOUR FLIP. BLACK NODE HEIGHT DOES NOT CHANGE
       P.COLOUR = BLACK
       U.COLOUR = BLACK
       G.COLOUR = RED
       'BUT G's PARENT COULD BE RED, SO LOOP AGAIN WITH NEW N BEING G
       N = G
    ELSE
       'PARENT IS RED AND UNCLE IS BLACK
       IF N IS ON INSIDE UNDERNEATH G
           ROTATE OUTWARDS ABOUT P
           N = P
       END IF
       'N IS ON OUTSIDE
       ROTATE ABOUT G TOWARD U
       P.COLOUR = BLACK 'NEW GRANDFATHER
       G.COLOUR = RED   'NEW UNCLE
       'N.COLOUR = RED  'NO CHANGE
       RETURN
    END IF


ENDLOOP
```

Comment: but even without the "N" node, the tree should not be a valid red-black tree either, isn't it?

Comment: Xiaodong: No you are correct. But the diagram is a red-black tree in the process of being fixed up. When you do an Insert or Delete, you may temporarily violate the Red-Black tree properties. For an Insert, you may violate the fact that you have a Parent & Child both red. For Delete, you may violate the fact that the black tree count in every path is not the same. Fixups towards the root will repair the tree. This can always be done. The OP's picture was a stage in this. It is not a red-black tree, yet, but will be once repairs are complete.